# Instagram API Rates Limits

Tags: javascript, php, instagram, instagram-api

I'm creating a web app that uses the relationships permission from instagram API.

But the endpoint for use the relationships for sandbox calls are 30 per hour and for Live clients are 60 per hour.

As use of case I have a friend that have more than 2000 requests to follow every day. Accept a request of follow is a change in the relationships.

How can I handle all this calls if I can only make 60 calls if my app gets approved?

The web app work's great, it's not a code problem, it's a doubt about the rate limits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lot of people were creating apps using API to auto follow and gaming the system to gain likes and followers, so Instagram lowered the rate limits to avoid this, not much you can do about it.

Comment: It's sad. I sent a email to the instagram support a few days ago and got nothing.